# Separar campo pai e filho de uma mesma tabela em uma linha no oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Possuo uma tabela que tem um relacionamento pai e filho:

| código | produto | cod pai | grau |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | torta banana | 10 | 3 |
| 2 | torta maçã | 11 | 3 |
| 10 | banana | 111 | 2 |
| 11 | maçã | 111 | 2 |
| 111 | fruta | -9999999 | 1 |

Eu preciso trazer os campos "filhos" e os seus "ancestrais". A tabela que eu uso vai até o grau 4. Preciso de um resultado semelhante a este:

| Código | Produto | Cod Pai1 | nome Pai1 | Cod Pai2 | nome Pai2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Torta Banana | 10 | Banana | 111 | Fruta |
| 2 | Torta maça | 11 | maça | 111 | Fruta |
| 10 | Banana | 111 | fruta | -9999999 |  |
| 111 | fruta | -999999 |  |  |  |

Atualmente eu consigo chegar a esse resultado ligando a tabela a ela mesma. Ex:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABELA1 TAB1 
   INNER JOIN TABELA1 PAI1 ON TAB1.CODPAI = PAI1.CODIGO
   INNER JOIN TABELA1 PAI2 ON PAI1.CODPAI = PAI2.CODIGO
```

Porém a tabela no qual eu preciso fazer essa consulta é muito grande e o resultado ficou muito pesado. Existe algum modo onde eu consiga chegar ao resultado de exemplo sem fazer essa ligação de tabela x mesma tabela?

Comment: Não seria o caso de utilizar uma consulta recursiva? [Talvez auxilie](https://www.devmedia.com.br/armazenando-relacionamentos-hierarquicos-em-bancos-de-dados-relacionais-revista-sql-magazine-104/25970).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm#SQLRF52335